# How to get form bean value in JSP in struts 1.x

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I need to get form bean value in jsp in struts 1.x

I am trying following code but that doesn't help.

```html
<c:forEach begin="1" end='here I need that from bean value' var="i"  >
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${param.pageNumberInput eq i}">
            <td>
                <c:out value="${i}" />
            </td>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <td>
                <a href="#"><c:out value="${i}" /> </a>
            </td>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

I can get form bean value using the following tag

But when I try like this it doesn't work

```html
<c:forEach begin="1" end='<bean:write name="formBeanName" property="propertyName" />'   var="i"  >
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${param.pageNumberInput eq i}">
            <td>
                <c:out value="${i}" />
            </td>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <td>
                <a href="#"><c:out value="${i}" /></a>
            </td>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Please help how to get this `formBean` property value.

Comment: `propertyName` has getter? and have you added any bean instance with key as `formBeanName`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
end='${formBeanBame.propertyName}'
```

You can't use a JavaServer Pages (JSP) tag in an attribute of another JSP tag. And The JSP Expression Language (EL) is all you need to access properties of beans.