# How to make JavaServer Pages (JSP) Expression Language (EL) throw an error if i have an invalid expression?

Tags: jsp

I am trying to use JavaServer Pages (JSP) Expression Language (EL) syntax to output a value. [For example:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22951780)

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
   Hello, ${formBeanBame.propertyName}
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, i don't know what my expression should be. I don't know if the same `formBeanName` is valid. (i just saw it randomly on another question) It is almost certain that using `formBeanName` is not correct. (I certainly don't remember ever creating an object, class, variable, or configuration file name with a value of `formBeanName`).

So i **need** JSP EL to tell me when the expression is invalid.

I can confirm that `formBeanName` is not a magic sentinel-value, and it simply is eating errors, by changing my code to:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
   Hello, ${asdfasgfarsdfh.propertyName}
</body>
</html>
```

And it still raises no error, and simply outputs:

> Hello,

How can i make JSP EL tell me when I've made a mistake.

**Bonus Question**: What **is** the name of my *form bean name*, and how would i know?

Comment: There's no way *we* know what the name of your "form bean" is (nor do we know what a "form bean" is in this context). JSP EL searches available scopes to resolve names; you can examine whatever processes the request and see what's exposed in the EL scopes (with the caveat that *anything* in the request processing flow can modify those scopes, e.g., filters, interceptors, other framework artifacts, etc.)

Comment: You can also dump out the objects in a given scope (useful during debugging) to see what's there and their values, e.g., for the request scope (roughly) `<c:forEach items="${requestScope}" var="v">${v.key} = ${v.value}<br/></c:forEach>`

Comment: @DaveNewton That is an excellent debugging snippet to have in ones toolbox. It then let me see the *actual* name of the *"request scope"* key that was added by **Struts** to my request. Yes JSP EL doesn't raise an error for in invalid name, this way i can get the real name and move on with my day.

Comment: In Struts 1 the form bean is named in the config file, IIRC. In Struts 2 there's no official form bean as such and exposed properties are based on JavaBean naming conventions.

Comment: *"In Struts 2 there's no official form bean as such and exposed properties are based on JavaBean naming conventions"* All the more reason to wish JSP EL would tell me when i have the wrong name!